Salesforce LWC - window.open()
I have been using window.open() in one of my salesforce LWC components for a number of years without issue, this call is used to open an external page (not Salesforce). Recently i have begun to see the below error, only when triggering window.open() if previous window is left open.
In my LWC i have a window.open() call that is triggerd on click of a record e.g.
var urlString = "test.com/rec/{Dynamic id based record selected}"
window.open("https://" + urlString,"quote","width="+window.screen.availWidth+",height="+window.screen.availHeight);

If i leave the previous popup open and click another record, the existing window would be overriden due to using the same name "newquote" which was what i wanted.
Recently i have started to see the below error in the console:
"error during openSecurityError: Permission denied to access property "eval" on cross-origin object"
Is there a way to overcome this?
I can use the _blank instead of a name when preforming the calls, however if i do this then the previous popup isnt overrdden and needs to be manually closed each time which is not ideal.

Googling for "openSecurityError" cross-origin doesn't produce a single result, which is surprising. Neither does "error during openSecurityError" sound plausible. Is this the exact error message? Is this on Firefox? From inside an iframe? What make you think the error comes from the open call and not from the reference to screen? I've tried to reproduce anything like it, but failed.
